# What is the purpose of grub-common.service?

Tags: systemd

I am tuning the start up of my machine and noticed that grub-common.service was at the top of `systemd-analyze blame 12.628s grub-common.service`

Can this service be **safely** disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the source https://github.com/JoliOS/grub2/blob/1efdfd9afceeb08661a5ae0565b3651fdf180601/debian/grub-common.init
it records successful boot for GRUB.

```
# Description:       GRUB displays the boot menu at the next boot if it
#                    believes that the previous boot failed. This script
#                    informs it that the system booted successfully.
```

Also if $VERBOSE is set (non `silent` mode, I assume), it logs it's actions.

So in theory if you disable this service, every time you restart your machine, grub menu will popup. Of course you can set up appropriate timeouts in `/etc/default/grub`. Beware, if you set up too low timeouts you might end up in the situation with cycling reboot and overgrowing logs, which cannot be rotated or archived.

Be sure you have liveCD just in case.